# Convert image to png byte array in Matlab

Tags: matlab, compression, png

I would like to take a 512x512 image and convert it into a png byte array in Matlab so that I can stream it via a socket.

At the moment I take the array, write it to a png file using imwrite(I,'file.png'), then read it as a binary file and send it through the socket. This is obviously horribly inefficient because I first write to disk and then read from disk. I want to skip the and write to disk.

Is there anyway to do this in Matlab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not directly using the base MATLAB toolbox since the PNG file itself is created by the `PNGWRITEC` MEX-function. However, there may be some Java classes that can help, such as those in the `javax.imageio` package.

Comment: Thats perfect. I just did a import javax.imageio.* and I now have access to all the methods I need.